# How to override luigi complete() method so that the underlying task will come to know the previous ones were completed?

Tags: python, shell, luigi

I have the following tasks :

```
class TaskA(ExternalProgramTask):
    def program_args(self):
        return ["/simpleScripts/shell5.bash"]
    def program_environment(self):
        env = os.environ.copy()
        return env
```

The shell script is running properly. After this if I try to run any other task , those task will fail by throwing "unfulfilled dependency error" in TaskA.

The reason I understood is usually Luigi will have output() method where a localTarget is created and thus Luigi will come to know that that Task is completed.

Here while running shell script I don't have any localTarget and thus 
luigi fails to understand whether it is completed or not. How to make this correct ?

Comment: why dont you just dump a target file when your script is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the complete method of Luigi and return true if all the desired operations are completed

```
class TaskA(luigi.Task):
    data_text = luigi.Parameter()

    def complete(self):
        print("The task is complete")
        print("The data text", self.data_text)
        return True
```

luigi --module [File_Name] TaskA --data-text "Welcome" --local-scheduler